# How to keep original shape size using OpenCvSharp.ApproxPolyDP

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, drawing, polygon

I am using OpenCvSharp.ApproxPolyDP to reduce the number of points in a polygon. However, this algorithm changes the original shape of the shape and produces cut corners. Is it possible to optimize the number of points in a polygon and keep the original shape?

Before poly optimization:
[image]

After poly optimization:
[image]

Expected (red):
[image]

The code that I'm using:

```
OpenCvSharp.Cv2.ApproxPolyDP(polyPoints, tempThreshHold, true)
```

Comment: What value has the `tempThreshHold` parameter? Looks like the value is too high.

Comment: This is just an example here is a really big value in the threshold variable. In some cases, the optimization cuts off the corner of the object, in some cases, it cuts off one side (a little). The idea is to keep the original size of the polygon

Comment: approxPolyDP only removes points. it never adds/changes points. it is an *approximation*, not an optimization. you are removing too many points because the tolerance you give (threshold) is too big for these contours. if you want a bounding box, you need a different function.

Comment: I don't need a bounding box. I want an approximate polygon without changing the shape size to avoid cutting the edges.